# How to specify images to be used as thumbnails for facebook sharing

Tags: php, facebook, meta-tags

I am making a website gallery page, and in the meta tags I have set an og:image, so when someone clicks like on the page, the image is used as the story's thumbnail on their facebook wall.

When someone shares a link, they only have the option to use the image above as the story's thumbnail. Is there a way to add more images as options for the story's thumbnail so the user can use the arrows and select the image they want?

If I used more than one og:image tags, would they have that option? And if so, how would the like button's thumbnail image be selected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the multi image selector on Facebook, you would need to remove the `og:image` from the page being requested and just have a bunch of `img` tags.

Facebook will scrape all the `img` tags and offer them as choices.

To detect the facebook scraper, and show different content specific for the scrape, just detect the user agent below, and output different content (i.e. only the og tags you want, and a set of img tags):

`facebookexternalhit/1.1 (+http://www.facebook.com/externalhit_uatext.php)`

Comment: Is there a way to unselect some image tags from the scraping, since the are used in the appearance of the page ( A lot of external links are not text but img tagged images. )

Comment: You could detect the Facebook scraper and not output certain images if it is from the facebook scraper, or show a whole different set of content. According to one article I looked up the header is `facebookexternalhit/1.0 (+http://www.facebook.com/externalhit_uatext.php)`